# How to detect tone sequences through the audio input?

Tags: sound, microphone

I would like to take a sound input from a microphone, and detect a two-tone sequence, like is done with old-school pagers for EMS and fire. It is usually 2 1-second tones, in the 100s of Hz range. Each different frequency combination of tones can have different meanings.

When a tone sequence is detected, I would like to be able to perform an action (like send an email, run a script, etc.). I can make the action scripts, I just need to know if anyone has created the tone detector part and how they did it.